# ReWrite Rules Issue

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url, url-rewriting

I seem to be having an issue with my Apache Rewrites

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteBase / 
RewriteRule ^wordpress/?$ / [NC,L,R=301] 

RewriteRule ^/$ wordpress/ [NC,L]
```

I simply need to remove /wordpress from the URL as I have pages within Wordpress I want to be seen as the main directory

At the moment the urls are

domain.com/wordpress/blog

I'd rather not have /wordpress, rather domain.com/blog

Any help?

Comment: You must have to check if the file inside exists or not, and then use rewriterule.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^wordpress/(.*)$ blog/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

> At the moment the urls are
>
> domain.com/wordpress/blog
>
> I'd rather not have /wordpress, rather domain.com/blog

So it looks like you want to **redirect** the browser if someone makes a request for `domain.com/wordpress/` to a URL without the `wordpress` bit, then **internally rewrite** the `wordpress` bit *back into the URI*? That's definitely do-able but if you have wordpress rewrite rules somewhere they're not going to play nicely with each other at all.

Any rules in the `/wordpress` directory will supercede any rules you put in the document root, which is where these rules need to go, and your remove-the-wordress-from-URI rules will be completely ignored. Even if you have rule inheritance turned on, the rules in the `/wordpress` directory will get executed first.

If all of your wordpress rules are actually in the document root's htaccess file, then just make sure to put these **before** the wordpress ones:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase / 

# redirect the browser if someone makes a request for domain.com/wordpress/
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /wordpress/
RewriteRule ^/?wordpress/(.*)$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# internally rewrite the wordpress bit back into the URI
RewriteRule %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/wordpress%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
RewriteRule %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/wordpress%{REQUEST_URI} -d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /wordpress/$1 [L]
```